# How to create animated PNG in Linux

Tags: png

I found that using PhotoShop anyone can create an animated PNG file in Windows. Is it possible in Linux too? Is there an application which can generate animated PNG files in Linux?

Comment: I haven't tried, but this may help: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/apngasm.1.html

Comment: check out the following links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795518/using-ffmpeg-to-create-looping-apng
 https://superuser.com/questions/92495/convert-video-to-apng-png

Comment: I did a simple web search using the words: create animated PNG in Linux. I found multiple alternatives. You might search some of these and read the page descriptions to see if these might meet your need, then modify your question to ask if others have used that choice and how easy it was to do so or just install and try one that looks good. You can always remove it if it is not to your liking.